# How to print strings that have more consonants than vowels?

Tags: c, arrays, string, for-loop, char

Enter the array of 20 strings. Make program that prints out strings which have more consonants than vowels and in which letter 'r' is repeated at least 3 times.

I belive that the problem is in my if loops, but somehow i fail to understand why it does not work properly. It prints every string I enter.

This is the code i wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>


    int main(void) {

    char string[20][50];
    int i, j;
    int vowels=0;
    int consonants=0;
    int repeated_r=0;

    printf("Enter the array of 20 strings:\n");

    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        gets(string[i]);
        }

    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        for(j=0;j<50;j++){

            if(string[i][j] == 'r'){
                repeated_r++;
            }
            else if(string[i][j] == 'a' || string[i][j] == 'e' || string[i][j] == 'i' || string[i][j] == 'o' || string[i][j] == 'u'){
                vowels++;
            }
            else{
                consonants++;
            }

        }
        if(consonants>vowels && repeated_r>=3){

            fflush(stdin);
            puts(string[i]);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `r` is a consonant, so if you have the word `turreteer` it will not be printed because you'll count 3 `r`, 4 vowels and 2 consonants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting the initial values of the variables in the outer loop

```
int vowels=0;
int consonants=0;
int repeated_r=0;
```

Also the condition in the inner loop

```
for(j=0;j<50;j++){
        ^^^^
```

is not correct because in this case there is an access to memory beyond stored strings in the array.

The letter `'r'` is not counted as a consonant.

Take into account that the function `gets` is not a standard C function that is it is not supported by the C Standard any more.

And this call

```
fflush(stdin);
```

has undefined behavior.

I can suggest the following solution as shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { M = 3, N = 50 };
    char s[M][N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        fgets( s[i], N, stdin );
        s[i][strcspn( s[i], "\n" )] = '\0';
    }

    const char *vowels = "aeiou";
    const char r = 'r';

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        size_t repeated_r = 0;
        size_t vowels_count = 0;
        size_t n = strlen( s[i] );

        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            repeated_r += s[i][j] == r;
            vowels_count += strchr( vowels, s[i][j] ) != NULL;
        }

        if ( repeated_r >= 3 && vowels_count < n - vowels_count )
        {
            puts( s[i] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the following strings

```
    Hello World
    errors
    photosynthesis_bro
```

then the program output might look like

```
errors
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the counters after processing each string.

And don't use `gets` use `fgets` instead.

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    for(j=0;j<50;j++){

        if(string[i][j] == 'r'){
            repeated_r++;
        }
        else if(string[i][j] == 'a' || string[i][j] == 'e' || string[i][j] == 'i' || string[i][j] == 'o' || string[i][j] == 'u'){
            vowels++;
        }
        else{
            consonants++;
        }

    }
    if(consonants>vowels && repeated_r>3){

        fflush(stdin);
        puts(string[i]);
    }

   //Reset the counters
    consonants =0;
    vowels =0;
    repeated_r =0;
  }
 }
```

Also note that in your current code `r` is not considered as consonant.

Answer (score 0):

there is one more problem in your code, ypu're using gets. It'll also include white spaces so say if your string is "_ _ *rrrbaeeeeiou* _ *". It will print this string but actually this string should not have been printed.
Note that "*" means a blank space.
According to your code, "_" will be counted in consonants and even though there are 4 consonants in your string(3 r and 1 b) and 8 vowels, it will print this string as output since the blank spaces will be counted as consonants.
Also in your code r is not counted as consonant